# Create a simple Android and iOS application without any code

Tags: software-development, user-interface

The Microsoft [Windows App Studio](http://appstudio.windows.com/en-us?stay=1) is an online tool that you can use to create fully operable apps for both Windows Store and Windows Phone. It has simple features such as:

- Custom startup images, color themes and basic custom UI
- Use of data feeds such as RSS, public Facebook, Instagram, etc.
- Ability to generate packages *and* source code for further customization

Here’s a little more detail of how easy the interface for creating an app in the Windows App Studio is:

[image: Main Interface]

1. I can easily create the name and configure different parts of the application such as content, themes, titles, etc.
2. Adding content to the application is extremely simple (yet limited).

   [image: Adding Content]
3. Say I wanted to add a Facebook feed. You give it a section name and the Facebook user name. That's it!

   [image: Finished Result]
4. The content is configurable, and there can be multiple feeds.
5. A preview of the app is right there ready to be tested.

I’m looking for an application (either Web or desktop: OS X, Windows, or Linux) that allows me to do the same but for Android and iOS apps.

Is there one that exists?

Comment: If it’s not a web-based solution: for which OS?

Comment: @unor Any OS honestly.  I have mac, windows, and linux machines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [MIT App Inventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu/):

- free
- create Android app graphically through a web interface:

[image]

Comment: this is slightly more complicated that I was looking for (see my edits).  Also what about iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Buzztouch (http://www.buzztouch.com/) allows the creation of native (i.e. "real" and no wrapped mobile websites) apps for iOS Android. It is free and works in the browser. The UI is not as modern as the one from Windows App Studio, but you do not have to create the application logic on your own (like App Inventor does).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [WaveMaker Rapid](http://www.wavemaker.com/rapid/): it lets you create Android and iOS apps without code

1. Design the app visually with drag & drop:

[image]

2. Integrate with own databases/3rd party/custom APIs:

[image]

3. Deploy anywhere:

[image]

The apps will work in all devices/all OS versions without the need for coding or cumbersome device/OS app testing.

Advantages:

- Based on open-standards
- IDE interoperable
- Flexibility in deployment
- API driven app development
- Scalable
- 1 month trial option + moderate pricing

Hope this helps!