# A tool for "code only" Java Android development

Tags: android, software-development, java, eclipse

I'm developing a Java application which should run primarily on Android, but desktop is strongly considered and iOS may be a nice bonus. As the GUI is by far not the core (estimated 10-20% development time on desktop), I started with the business logic and some rudimentary desktop GUI using Swing.

There are [tools allowing to develop without any code](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10432/8815) and what I'm looking for is *exactly the opposite*. A tool allowing to compose the GUI in pure Java, no drag and drop, no generated code, and (if possible) no XML. I found out that using something like [miglayout](http://www.miglayout.com) works best for me (I don't expect to ever see a GUI builder compatible with me).

I have a lot of experience with Eclipse IDE, and only a very limited experience with it for Android. For desktop I'm perfectly happy with Eclipse, for Android it was not satisfactory because of the very slow emulator and re-occurring strange configuration problems. I'm considering [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com), but haven't even downloaded it yet; I hope to get a helping answer first.